# Check range of Unicode Value of a character

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, unicode, unicode-escapes

In Objective-c...

If I have a character like "∆" how can I get the unicode value and then determine if it is in a certain range of values.

For example if I want to know if a certain character is in the unicode range of `U+1F300` to `U+1F6FF`

Comment: Good question. It's trivial if the char is <= `U+FFFF`. Just use `unichar`. I haven't seen a good method for chars >= `U+10000`.

Comment: @rmaddy Is `unichar` a method for determining what the unicode value of a character is under `U+FFFF` or is it a method for determining what range a given unicode value is in?

Comment: `unichar` is a data type. See the `NSString characterAtIndex:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy Worked good so far... when I tried NSLogging it I used `%hu` and it worked all the way up to `55357` ... then every unichar after that returned the value `55357` no matter how much higher I went... what to use other than `%hu`?

Comment: What do you mean by "have a character"? Where do you have it? How? Is it in a variable? Of what type? How is the character represented (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16)?

Comment: Nothing specific yet... but for the sake of example we can just say it's in a standard `NSString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` uses UTF-16 to store codepoints internally, so those in the range you're looking for (`U+1F300` to `U+1F6FF`) will be stored as a [*surrogate pair*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) (four bytes). Despite its name, `characterAtIndex:` (and `unichar`) doesn't know about codepoints and will give you the two bytes that it sees at the index you give it (the `55357` you're seeing is the *lead surrogate* of the codepoint in UTF-16).

To examine the raw codepoints, you'll want to convert the string/characters into UTF-32 (which encodes them directly). To do this, you have a few options:

1. Get all UTF-16 bytes that make up the codepoint, and use either [this algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#utf16-3) or [`CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair) to convert the surrogate pairs to UTF-32.
2. Use either `dataUsingEncoding:` or `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:` to convert the `NSString` to UTF-32, and interpret the raw bytes as a `uint32_t`.
3. Use a library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).